# Capturing output from GradleBuild

Tags: gradle

From one Gradle project, I want to, essentially, call `./gradlew dependencies` for another unrelated project (not multi-project build). It looks like the way to do this is using the `GradleBuild` task, however I'm having some troubles with that.

Namely, how do I get the stdout from the GradleBuild invocation to process it? Unlike JavaExec, there's no obvious stream configuration parameters.

I've also looked a bit into `WorkerExecutor#processIsolation()`, but none of the options there seem relevant. I thought it might make sense to modify the JVM-wide stdout configuration, but this only makes sense if it's in a forked process.